# What does "Bunk over" mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Here is a quote from The Avengers, 2012:

> - Stark : The next building is gonna say "Potts" on the tower.
> - Pepper : On the lease.
> - Stark : Call your mom. Can you bunk over?

Q. "The building is gonna say "Potts" on the tower" What does exactly it mean?
Maybe it means "The building is gonna be hung out a sign written her name, Potts on the tower?"

Q. Pepper said "On the lease". She meant "You should sign on the lease contract"?

Q. Lastly, I have no idea what Stark's last line means, specially "bunk over"
And why Stark wants Pepper to call her mother suddenly. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: just FYI a "bunk" is a bed; it makes you think of a simple bed - perhaps like at a camp or a military base.  you know in English people say "I'll sleep over on your couch" .. it's the same sort of thing.

Comment: Your first question - Yes.  Your third question - the idea is "ask your Mom, if you are allowed to sleep here tonight."  The middle question, it probably relates to a lease contract but it's hard to tell in the context.  Cheers! :)  great TV show isn't it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Stark : The next building is gonna say "Potts" on the tower.
>
> "This building says "Stark" on the tower. The next one is going to say "Potts" on the tower"

They're talking about the "next building" after Stark Tower, aka the Tower that has Stark written in big letters outside. So yes, he's saying let's have the next building (with arc reactor energy etc) be Potts Tower, with Potts written in big letters on the actual building.

> Pepper : On the lease.
>
> "The next building is going to say "Potts", but only on the lease"

Pepper, otoh, has no interest in having her name in big letters outside a building. She's saying the next tower will indeed have her name on it, but only on paper - she'll own it, but she feels no need to see her name splashed on the outside. Edit: It might also refer to Potts not wanting the next building to be *named* Potts Tower either, for much the same reasons.

> Stark : Call your mom. Can you bunk over?
>
> "Call your mom. Can you stay over?"

This one is purely tongue-in-cheek. Stark is basically just asking if she can stay over / not go to her own place / business meetings / whatever, but doing so while acting like they're teens and she needs her mom's permission in order to stay over.

Comment: As for my second question, I just want you to let it this straight for me. I've guessed given that the whole context, she answered jokingly "on the lease" (and that means "you specify it on the lease in order to assure it). I think you watched this movie before, so I would like confirm again. Are you sure your first answer is what she meant? and my guess above doesn't make sense and is unnatural? I apologize in advance if my English was so poor.

Comment: I don't think she meant 'you should specify it on / you should sign the lease'. I think she just meant 'Yes, the next building will have my name, but... only on the lease'. It's not Stark's building being gifted to her, she's the CEO of Stark Industries.

Comment: Re: first one, I'm definitely sure that's what was meant :) "Next Building" only makes sense if there's a "this building" and the only "this building" possible is Stark Tower. And the fact that Stark hung up a big sign with his name on his building is repeatedly considered noteworthy about the whole building. In addition it probably also might refer to Potts not wanting the next tower to be _named_ Potts Tower (similar to Stark Tower) either. Which is a good point and I'll edit my answer to reflect this. :)

Answer (score 2):

It means:

To stay the night; sleep: bunk over at a friend's house.